# Is there a lstset for the latex language itself

Tags: lstlisting

I would like to have a bit of latex code inside my pdf. I am using lstlisting by having hard time asking the right question to my search engine as request like "lstset for latex" obviously do no give the results i want.

An example of code i would like to print is the following:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\textbf{TikZ code generation},captionpos=b]
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.156250, -0.265165) rectangle (0.250000, -0.176776);
    ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: If you want to find out how to use a package or which features are available, then a good place to start is the package manual. Most packages are listed on CTAN, the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. You can you to [ctan.org](http://www.ctan.org) and search for your package to find the manual, in this case http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf. On page 13 you find the list of default supported languages with the identifier to activate the syntax highlighting. Apart from CTAN, you can also enter `texdoc somepackage` (so here `texdoc listings`) in a terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `language={[latex]TeX}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[latex]TeX}]
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.156250, -0.265165) rectangle (0.250000, -0.176776);
    ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```